# código de barra para angular 9 o mayor

Tags: angular

> Necesito generar código de barra en angular 9 o mayor, todos los que
> encuentro son viejos y no se cual esta activo o actualizado. Me pueden
> ayudar ?. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes pasarte por esta libreria

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-barcode

La cual tiene un demo

https://yobryon.github.io/ngx-barcode/demo/

Esta basada en JsBarcode

Comment: Gracias , lo voy a probar